# I am using django 3.2.5 version in DB opretions in views.py ".objects" method couldn't retrive data from models, please give any suggestions?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-views

**settings.py**

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'TempInherApp', ]`

**moddels.py**

from django.db import models

`class Employee(models.Model):      idno = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)      name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)      salary = models.FloatField()`

**views.py**

[image: views.py screen shot]

from django.shortcuts import render
from TempInherApp.models import Employee

`def view_emp(request): result = Employee.objects.all() print(result) return render(request, "Blog.html", {"data": result})`

**Database(sqlite3)**

[image: Database data]

**template interface**

[image: Blank template]

I pushed data successfully into the database,but can't retrive data from database, even when i ran server it's not thowing any error to me.

python 3.8
django 3.2.5

Comment: Share template code Blog.html

Comment: {% extends 'common.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <table align="center" border="2">
        <tr>
            <th width="100">Idno</th>
            <th width="200">Name</th>
            <th width="200">Salary</th>
        </tr>
        {% for x in data %}

            <tr>
                <th>{{ x.idno }}</th>
                <th>{{ x.name }}</th>
                <th>{{ x.salary }}</th>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

{% endblock%}

Comment: In views.py, what is output of statement print(result)? Is it empty queryset?

Comment: File "c:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/DjangoProject/TemplateInheritance/TempInherApp/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from TempInherApp.models import Employee
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TempInherApp'

Comment: but i have app file, why it's showing     from TempInherApp.models import Employee ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TempInherApp'

Comment: make sure 'TempInherApp' is present in  INSTALLED_APPS. Just for checking use from .models import Employee. Debug your code , it will minor issue.